# Maven - set it not to repackage jar dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to do in maven the same as what Eclipse does in the export runnable jar by checking "package required libraries into generated jar" as in the picture below
[image: Eclipse option image]

here is my pom "build" section:

```xml
<build>
        <finalName>MFZ_${version}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>com.co.mfz.Main</Main-Class>
                                        <Build-Number>${version}</Build-Number>
                                        <Class-Path>./ ./config/common/ ./config ./img ./ecc </Class-Path>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
</build>
```

Right now once I run my application I got

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:321)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:762)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1033)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:883)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:848)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:780)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:675)
```